# Where can I find word games and puzzles?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Where can I find downloadable word games for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

1. Launch the Ubuntu Software Centre, by clicking on its icon in the launcher on the left of the screen.

   [image: Launcher]
2. Once the Software Centre has launched, click on the "Games" category.

   [image]
3. Click on the "Puzzles" category

   [image]
4. You'll see a list of games for free and for purchase which can be installed immediately.

   [image: Puzzles category]

You can also find games for Ubuntu on [Steam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/), in [Humble Indie Bundles](https://www.humblebundle.com/), and on other websites.

In general, most software for Ubuntu can be found in the Ubuntu Software Centre, but you can also find software for Ubuntu online on websites as well. Installing software from the Centre is quite easy, whereas installing software from a `.deb` or a `.tar.gz` file is less easy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question for finding word puzzles.

I found this one named Klest-crossword (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/klest-crossword-crossword-puzzle-game-and-creator-for-ubuntu-linux/). It has ~1000 crosswords for both Russian and English, and can automatically generate new ones. But it's too difficult for me...

As mentioned above, GBrainy (in software center) is another choice for verbal game. But that's not what I looking for...

Answer (score 0):

[Simon Tatham's Portable Puzzle Collection](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/) is fun, also demanding when the default setting is changed.

The collection is available for [Linux](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/puzzles.tar.gz), [OS X](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/Puzzles.dmg) and [windows](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/puzzles.zip). Instructions for all 39 games (all in all under 20MB) can be found here > [HTML Help](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/puzzles.chm) <

---

After compiling with `./configure & make install` you're good to go.