# searching for a memory and brain games in ubuntu

Tags: games

is there any recommendation for games to train the brain in Ubuntu or in Linux , did any one try a game and it was a good one on ubuntu

Comment: I posted an answer that my be of interest to you here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270803/where-can-i-find-word-games-and-puzzles/327406#327406

Answer (score 0):

gbrainy. Most probably it's already installed on your ubuntu.